# Disable signed and view envelope notifications

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to disable the email notifications I get when someone views or finishes signing an envelope. If possible, I could like to disable ALL notifications through the rest xml api.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd like to do this through REST or just in general? This is easier to do through the web console.

Comment: I want to and I must do it through REST.

Comment: The thing is I am using docusign inside my own app, so I am trying to eliminate any docusign branding or notification, so that people do not know docusign is my backend.

Answer (score 0):

***It sounds like you want to Modify User Account Settings***

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20User%20Account%20Settings.htm

**Sample Request:**

```
PUT https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/settings



    X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>

    Accept: application/json

    Content-Type: application/json



    {

      "userSettings": [

        {

          "name": "sting",

          "value": "string"

        },

        {

          "name": "string",

          "value": "string"

        }

      ],

      "signerEmailNotifications": {

        "envelopeActivation": " string ",

        "envelopeComplete": " string",

        "carbonCopyNotification": "string",

        "certifiedDeliveryNotification": "string",

        "envelopeDeclined": "string",

        "envelopeVoided": "string",

        "envelopeCorrected": "string",

        "reassignedSigner": "string",

        "purgeDocuments": "string",

        "faxReceived": "string",

        "documentMarkupActivation": "string",

        "agentNotification": "string"

      },

      "senderEmailNotifications": {

        "envelopeComplete": "string",

        "changedSigner": "string",

        "senderEnvelopeDeclined": "string",

        "withdrawnConsent": "string",

        "recipientViewed": "string",

        "deliveryFailed": "string"

      }

    }
```

**Response:**

The response returns success or failure.

Comment: Hi, Can you give me an example using XML?

Comment: Also, is there a page with all the APIs in XML?

Comment: <settings>
  <name="string" value="string"/>
 </settings>

Comment: Hi, I have the example of my request body, it still does not work:

string requestBody = "<settings xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" + "<senderEmailNotifications>" + "<envelopeComplete>false</envelopeComplete>" + "</senderEmailNotifications>" +"</settings>";

Comment: Hi, Ok i did it on json and it still does not work, I have:

            string requestBody = "{" +
                                 "\"signerEmailNotifications\":" +
                                  "{" +
                                    "\"envelopeActivation\":\"false\"" +
                                  "}" +
                                "}";